# Remove blue selection bar around form

Tags: html, css

I know for links the css is

```
a:focus {
text-decorations: none;
-mozselectedsomethingorother: none;
}
```

or something like that, but is there a way to remove the blue border

http://cl.ly/1d20272p36180S3f1c36

Comment: Give this as an answer Adam, not as a comment ;) credits for you

Comment: Beautiful! New there was a simple fix. I feel like an idiot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an anchor wrapped around an image, this css should work:

```
a img { border:none; }
a:focus { outline: none; }
```

And....someone already answered in the comments :-)

Comment: It's not an image, nor is there an anchor. It's a form.

Comment: `outline: 0` or `outline: none` is the answer, for everything

Answer (score 0):

```
text-decoration: none;
```

not decorations